# Where is the documentation for the Google Suggest API?

Tags: google-suggest

Is there any official documentation on the Google Suggest API?

All my searches for the Google suggest API show pages with either outdated info or non-working scripts.

For example, at google.com, as soon as you type in "app", Google suggests Apple, Applebees, etc.

Comment: As of 20160601 this works: http://google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=pickle for returning JSON

Comment: vote to reopen. This question is quite concise. it is not asking for recommendations of alternative tools to use, but rather asking how to use a specific tool (GoogleSuggestAPI)

Comment: @Mark , @ Angel Koh calling url with out api key, is there any violtion of terms.No need to create api key.Please Replay me need to create any api keys or create projectes in api console.

Answer (score 46):

As you can imagine, it's changed.

The newer URL is now http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&output=toolbar&q=YOURSEARCHTERM

Or even more recent:
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=YOURSEARCHTERM

Comment: Is it possible to get Json Results back?I tried ouput=json but just get a blank page.

Comment: Doesn't look like it works with this URL.  Sounds like big G are locking it down.

Comment: @chobo2 Using client=chrome currently works eg http://google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=YOURSEARCHEDTERM

Comment: @chobo2 imo nicer JSON result when using client=firefox

Comment: can i get results to contry specific ? any parameters as such.

Comment: @harvest316 calling url with out api key, is there any violtion of terms.No need to create api key.Please Replay me need to create any api keys or create projectes in api console.

Comment: Yeah looks like they want an API key now.

Answer (score 23):

**Summary of working examples:**

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25874492/1601703) working example:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=theory

---

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424599/nsurlrequest-with-url-containing-special-characters) working example:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&q=theory

---

From [mhawksey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027723/mhawksey) comment above working example:

http://google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=theory

Here `client=chrome` can be changed to other browser client. For example for Firefox it will look like:

http://google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=theory

---

From [mahoor13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514963/mahoor13) comment above working example:

[google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=theory](http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=theory)

---

From [dhiraj-pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954694/dhiraj-pandey) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25534944/1601703) "if you want country specific suggests, you need to add &gl= in the url". **That only works with links for toolbar!**

So for example working country specific example for India will be:

[google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=theory&gl=in](http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=theory&gl=in)

---

To separate words use `%20` or `+` between them. For example:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=a%20mykeyword

or

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=a+mykeyword

---

Also from [here](http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/11/quick-hack-tutorial-how-to-build-a-google-auto-suggest-comparison/) it possible to get two suggestions with YQL (first sugestion `chuck norris`, second `steven seagal`):

```
select * from xml where url in (
‘http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=chuck+norris’,
‘http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=steven+seagal’
)
```

Using above code gives:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20in%20%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Foutput%3Dtoolbar%26q%3Dchuck%2Bnorris%27%2C%27http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Foutput%3Dtoolbar%26q%3Dsteven%2Bseagal%27%29&format=xml&diagnostics=false

---

Some info from google about suggestions: http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/query_suggestion.html

Comment: calling url with out api key, is there any violtion of terms.No need to create api key.Please Replay me need to create any api keys or create projectes in api console.

Comment: What is the method for getting the suggestions even if there are spelling mistakes ? The suggestions you get when you write something into chrome toolbar with small spelling mistakes, -> it still suggests with correct spelling. These methods are autocomplete that only show results on correct spelling. (edit: There is room for super small spelling mistakes like: spelling a word with u that is suppose to be ú, but in the search bar I can have three different spelling mistakes in a long word and it still suggests the correct word)

Comment: >```http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20in%20%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Foutput%3Dtoolbar%26q%3Dchuck%2Bnorris%27%2C%27http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Foutput%3Dtoolbar%26q%3Dsteven%2Bseagal%27%29&format=xml&diagnostics=false

```

this is not working

Answer (score 17):

Try `http://google.com/complete/search?output=json&q=YOURSEARCHEDTERM` or for XML output `http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=YOURSEARCHEDTERM`

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1526-how-to-use-the-google-suggest-api-to-come-up-with-topics-for-answers/

I also found very interensting tool which use the Google Search API and it is based on Python and Flask [ubersuggest](http://ubersuggest.org/) and [keysuggest's Googlealphabet soup method tool](https://keysuggest.io/features/alphabet-soup).

Comment: This isn't working anymore.

Comment: I've test http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=theoric and the reslut is nice. +1

Comment: F that I was using the following query in a loop and I think that google got mad at me  but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now

Comment: calling url with out api key, is there any violtion of terms.No need to create api key.Please Replay me need to create any api keys or create projectes in api console.

Comment: `output=json` is not working now

Comment: I'm getting a result like this ```b'window.google.ac.h(["cars b",[["cars baby",0,[433]],["cars balls",0,[433,131]],["cars believer",0],["cars best scenes",0,[433]],["cars babybus",0],["cars broom broom",0],["cars big",0],["cars behind the scenes",0],["cars blippi",0],["cars badass scene",0],["cars birthday party decorations",0],["car bus",0,[10]],["cars bako",0],["cars balls colors",0]],{"k":1,"q":"T8vE-uLW0GB7wmCStE2meAzKDoc"}])'```


with my q = cars b

how can I make this into json format, the toolbar doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

As @Harvest316 said, you can use those urls to get suggestions, but if you want country specific suggests, you need to add &gl= in the url. For example, if I search for India, it will be

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=YOURSEARCHTERM&gl=in

Comment: calling url with out api key, is there any violtion of terms.No need to create api key.Please Replay me need to create any api keys or create projectes in api console.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I'm the author of [Übersuggest](http://ubersuggest.org/) the tool mentioned by JonnyPea. There is no **official** Google Suggest API: the URL I and other people use is just something we have found hacking around Google. Here's a couple of advice:

- Have a look at my application source code on Bitbucket (beware:
  I'm an hobbyist programmer so my code cold be improved **a lot**)
- **Do not** call the API thousands times from the same IP or you will be banned.

[UPDATE]

Sorry the source code is no more available

Comment: regarding ubersuggest, can I also look at your application code on Bitbucket too? thanks

Comment: How often would you call the API an hour without risking being banned?

Comment: @raben when reaching out your repo on bitbucket gives following error-
`You do not have access to this repository.`.
Can make available code in here ?

Comment: Oooo!  That would be awesome!  Yes, please, Raben!

Answer (score 2):

**There is a working API** that pulls data from Google Suggest (along with YouTube, Bing and App Store): http://keywordtool.io/api

Using this API you wouldn't need to worry about the number of requests from the same IP etc.

Google doesn't have an official API to share autocomplete data, moreover it often hides keywords that appear in Google suggest from Google Keyword Planner.

Note this API is by paid subscription and [starts at $280 / month](https://keywordtool.io/checkout?plan=api_v2_lite_monthly).

Comment: I got pretty excited about this until I saw the $88/mo price tag.

Comment: Can you suggest free APIs than commercial ones.

Comment: @Lenwood Haha same here, except it's now $280/mo :(