# Search function with automatic suggestions

Tags: iphone, ios, search

I want my user to be able to, when they are searching that under the text field they get choices. As en example if I am searching apple then under i get choices like apple, apple store, etc.I am very new to this topic. Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102878/google-suggest-api][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102878/google-suggest-api

Comment: you want to search data using webservices..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can Do, If The Data is With You

```
if([textField.text length] > 0 || textField.text != nil)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < [array1 count]; i++)
        {
                NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[array1 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"value"]];         
                if([[strName lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[newString lowercaseString]])
                {
                    [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Add This Code in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Add A `UITableView` below your `UITextField` According To your Frame. Display the Array2 Details in `UITableView`.

Try This it May Helps You