# How would I collect as many instances of the text: "[subject] are ..." from the web?

Tags: html, algorithm, web-services

I'm trying to collect statements from the web by searching for sentences with the following construction:

```
[subject] [are/is] [rest of sentence].
```

So for example, I want to search for and collect all sentences that start with "Computers are [rest of sentence]". Which would result in maybe things like:

- Computers are annoying.
- Computers are great.
- Computers are expensive.
- Etc.

What I want to collect is everything from the start of the sentence until the period (preferably sorted by the rate of occurence).

Is there a way to do this with existing search engines, or would I have to build a bot/scraper?

Comment: Maybe you can use Globalogic's [HTML Code Search Engine](http://globalogiq.com/htmlcodesearch.htm) that lets you search web pages at the HTML source level, and allows regular expressions. I haven't tried it, so it may not be able to do what you want.

Comment: @MrLister: Looks like a good idea, but they only collect html from home pages (so no nested pages). Which is rather unfortunate, because I'd like to search nested pages as well, otherwise the results could be rather sparse. Aside from that it's also a paid service, and I'd like to find a long term solution.

Comment: No real best or definitive answer. Basically this is difficult to do, and it either requires a lot of d.i.y. crawling or using pre-existing databases (and settling for what they're capable of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to start with a list of nouns you're interested, then pull up relevant sentences for each.

Does it need to be from the web?  There are a number of compilations of English that you can search through:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus

You'll still have to write some regular expressions to filter out what you don't want.

You could also use Google search API and search for things like `computers are *` you'll still need to filter the data.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't give you specific numbers, but you can get popular (often funny) results via the [Google Suggest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102878/google-suggest-api)

E.g:

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=Computers%20are
```

..which returns something like:

```
<toplevel>
<CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="computers are your future"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="computers are racist"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="computers are us"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="computers are stupid"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
  <suggestion data="computers are illegal in florida"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
[...]
</toplevel>
```

It's worth noting that Google will do it's usual magic to try and improve the results, e.g if you try to search the misspelled `Compuuter is`, it will be corrected to `Computer is`

Comment: I agree with this. No need to reinvent the wheel, unless it's for a school project. Teachers love to make students reinvent the wheel :D

Comment: That's kind of what I was looking for, but it only gives me about 8 results for each query. What I'm looking for is loads of results, as much as possible (and like you said, it doesn't give specific numbers, which makes further analysis a little more difficult).

Comment: @Samuel Yeh, it's pretty limited. You could try the regular Google Search API, which should give the estimated number of results for each suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using ruby, there's a library called spidr which can spider pages. There is also a library known as treat which is capable of NLP.

I'd also take a look at [yubnub](http://www.yubnub.org/)

Comment: I've looked into yubnub, but how would I use this to look for the information I'm trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to a massive corpus of web pages using the [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/) project.  Write a Hadoop MapReduce job to run on AWS and extract the pages you are interested in.  Details and tutorials are available on their site.